# When the Multiplier algebra of a Banach algebra is exactly equal to the operator algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

Let A be a Banach algebra. B(A) and M(A) be the operator algebra and the 
multiplier algebra of A, respectively. When we have M(A)=B(A)?

Comment: I imagine $A$ is commutative? Semisimple? _Is_ the "multiplier algebra" the set of bounded linear $T:A\to A$_Is_ $B(A)$ the algebra of bounded linear operators on $A$ and $M(A)$ the subalgebra consisting of operators $T$ with $\widehat{Tf}=m\hat f$ for some function $m$? If so I'd tend to doubt that they're ever the same except in the most trivial situations.

Comment: For example it's not even true in general for $C(K)$, $K$ compact hausdorff. Which is about the nicest Banach algebra in existence...

Comment: In fact it's always false for $C(K)$, $K$ compact Hausdorff, unless $K$ has only one point! Say $K$ has more than one point. Fix $p\in K$. Fix $\phi\in C(K)$ with $\phi\ne0$ but $\phi(p)=0$. Define $T:C(K)\to C(K)$ by $Tf=f(p)\phi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's false unless $A$ is one-dimensional.

First, it's false if $A$ has more than one complex homomorphism. Say $\phi$ and $\psi$ are distinct complex homomorphisms. Show that $\phi$ and $\psi$ are linearly independent.

Now choose $x_0\in A$ with $\psi(x_0)\ne0$ and define $T:A\to A$ by $$Tx=\hat x(\phi)x_0.$$So $$\widehat{Tx}(\psi)=\hat x(\phi)\psi(x_0)$$ If $T$ is given by the multiplier $m$ then $$\widehat{Tx}(\psi)=\hat x(\psi)m(\psi),$$showing that $\phi$ and $\psi$ are linearly dependent.

So now suppose that $A$ has only one complex homomorphism and $M(A)=B(A)$. Since the maximal ideal space consists of just one point, $M(A)$ has dimension $1$. Hence $B(A)$ has dimension $1$. Hence $A$ is one-dimensional (for example, if $X$ is any Banach space then there exists an injective linear map from the dual $X^*$ into $B(x)$: Fix $x_0\ne0$ in $X$, and map $x^*\in X^*$ to $T$, where $Tx=(x^*(x))x_0$.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was helpful. I look for a Banach algebra (nontrivial) such that the equality M(A)=B(A) holds.

Comment: @Zeinab There are no non-trivial examples. See edited version of my reply. (Don't forget to click the arrow and the checkmark...)

Comment: Is there any reference for this proof?

Comment: No idea, sorry...

Comment: In second paragraph you suppose that A has only one complex homomorphism and M(A)=B(A). Howevere we must suppose that M(A)=B(A) and then conclude that A is one-dimensional.